# Is a Do block the same as a With statement?

Tags: ruby, vb.net

Studying Ruby and the Do block.  Coming from much c# I didn't see much that reminded me of Do, but then VB came to mind with the With statement and one which I wish was in c# (maybe it is and I never saw it?).  The two statements, Do and With, appear similar.

Is the With statement in VB the same as a Do block in Ruby?

EDIT:

Take this example, ActiveRecord object TheBook, maps to database table:

```
TheBook.new do |book|
 book.title = "my book"
 book.writer = "some author"
end
```

I understand what I will get just from looking at it.  I know that I will get a new record in my database with the above information, but I do not know why.  Why did book become TheBook.new?  Do I read it from right to left?

Answer (score 8):

No. Ruby blocks (what you're delimiting with `do` and `end`) are basically [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). `with` in VB is just syntactic sugar to prevent you from needing to type the variable name over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

Being mainly a C# developer without much Ruby experience myself, I understand your confusion.

If you are familiar with the concept of [anonymous delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx) in C# 2.0 and [lambda expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/Lambda-Expressions.aspx) in C# 3.0, this makes a lot more sense.

Your Ruby ActiveRecord example could be expressed in C# 2.0 using anonymous delegates:

```
TheBook.New ((delegate TheBook book){
  book.title = "my book";
  book.author = "some author";
});
```

Or in C# 3.0 using a lambda expression as follows:

```
TheBook.New (book => {book.title = "my book"; book.author = "some author"});
```

Essentially the "do" block comes into play when you have methods that expect a function as an argument, or a delegate in C#.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the same. A Ruby block is an anonymous function (a closure, technically), that can be executed by the method it is passed to. For example, a snippet to get even numbers up to 100:

```
(1..100).select do |num| 
  num % 2 == 0
end
```

The `select` method calls the block with each number in the sequence as an argument to determine whether that number matches the selection criteria.

(Normally this would be written as `(1..100).select {|num| num%2 == 0}` — it makes no difference. The `do` syntax is exactly equivalent to the braces.)

Comment: I think one thing that throws me on this is that |num| is on the same line as do.  I have see others like yours that make more sense and some that have do { |somevar|...} that make more sense.

Comment: It's an argument. Think of it as the same as how a method's arguments are on the same line when you write `def mymethod(arg)`. The do-syntax is usually for multi-line blocks while the braces are usually used for single-line cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was WhyPoignant in his tutorial who explained it like this :

> `|varname|` is like a pipe to direct
>   the value of each iteration to the
>   block.

let say you want to read each line of a file :

```
file.each_line do |line|
  puts line
end
```

`file.each_line` give you some data, and you will use `|line|` to direct that data to the block (here just `puts line`)

Literraly : Read the file and for each line puts it on the screen (stdout to be precise)

I often write my code like that : `element`**s**`.each do |element| ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually learn a bit about what this method is doing by looking at the source.  From ActiveRecord::Base:

```
def initialize(attributes = nil)
  @attributes = attributes_from_column_definition
  @attributes_cache = {}
  @new_record = true
  ensure_proper_type
  self.attributes = attributes unless attributes.nil?
  self.class.send(:scope, :create).each { |att,value| self.send("#{att}=", value) } if self.class.send(:scoped?, :create)
  result = yield self if block_given?
  callback(:after_initialize) if respond_to_without_attributes?(:after_initialize)
  result
end
```

The line of interest for this question is `result = yield self if block_given?`.  In ruby, the yield method calls the block which has been passed into the function (in the example you gave, that would be the portion between `do` and `end`) with any parameters used.  In this case, the parameter yielded to the block is `self`.  This particular instance of a block, then, actually ends up replicating the `with` functionality you mentioned in Visual Basic, because it happens to pass the block the newly created ActiveRecord object - but, as discussed in other answers, Ruby blocks have many more uses than that.